# Школьная задачка, цикл for

Tags: python

**Даны два целых числа a и b**

Напишите программу, которая перебирает все целые числа от a до b и находит произведение тех из них, которые при умножении  на число 6 дают результат, оканчивающийся на цифру 2

---

*Входные данные:* 
**В первой строке вводятся два целых числа a и b (a<=b,  a,b не больше 100 по модулю)**

*Выходные данные:*
**Программа должна вывести одно число - произведение целых чисел от a до b, произведение которых на 6 оканчивается на 2. Если таких чисел нет, выведите 0**

---

Входные данные  Выходные данные
1 10                14

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Например так.

```
l = int(input());
r = int(input());
sum = 1;
for x in range( (l+2)//5*5+2, r+1, 5):
    sum = sum * x;
print(sum if sum>1 else 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
x = 1
for i in range(a, b):
    if (i * 6 % 10) == 2:
        x = x * i
print(x)
```